# How to return result base on current URL and define URL

Tags: php, regex

I want to check the current URL with the defined URL and return the result based on the result.

**Following is the code:**

```
<?php
$str = "/new-page/car-swift/";
$pattern = "/(/new-page/car-swift/)/i";
 if(preg_match($pattern, $str) ){
 echo "yes";
 }
 else
 echo "no";
?>
```

*Is there another way of doing this?*

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try checking your regex with a validator like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Always it return no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you're not escaping your `/` because you also use it as a delimiter:

```
/(\/new-page\/car-swift\/)/i
```

I'm not even sure if you need regex at all. You can simple compare the strings:

```
if (strcmp($str, "/new-page/car-swift/") === 0) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no'
}
```

Comment: yes you are right after changing patter it work as expected thank you and i need regular expression because i am getting url by using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] this function after that i am checking it with my predefine url

Comment: @dhirajthakare what does where you get the input value from, have to do with whether you would need regular expressions or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "/new-page/car-swift/";
$pattern = "/(\/new-page\/car-swift\/)/i";
 if(preg_match($pattern, $str) ){
 echo "yes";
 }
 else
 echo "no";
?>
```

try this i have tested this 100% working i  hope you got your solution .